# delete row data from firebase in angular 4

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2, smart-table

I am working on Angular 4 project I want to delete one clicked row from firebase

following is my smart table code

```
<ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="source" (edit)="onEdit($event)" (delete)="onDelete($event)">

    </ng2-smart-table>
```

the onDelete() function is as follow

```
onDelete(event) {
console.log(event);
    if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
      this.service.deleteEnquiry(event.data);
    } else {
      event.confirm.reject();
    }
  }
```

I have written deleteEnquiry function in service as follows

```
deleteEnquiry(data){
console.log(data);
this.af.list('/enquirydata/').remove(data);
}
```

but its not working for me it showing me following error in console

```
ERROR Error: Expects a string, snapshot, or reference.
```

any help?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
deleteEnquiry(data){
    console.log(data.$key);
    this.af.list(`/enquirydata/${data.$key}`).remove(data);
 }
```

Comment: where to close the curly brace

Comment: sorry for that i change my answer. check now

Comment: Dashboard1Component.html:14 ERROR Error: Expects a string, snapshot, or reference.

Comment: i want to see this console console.log(data);

Comment: if i used console.log(data.$key) its showing undefined.

Comment: if i used console.log(data) its giving me that row

Comment: in this row can you give firebase key ?

Comment: how should i do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165217/discussion-between-faisal-amdani-and-chirag-sorathiya).

Comment: when you get data from firebase at that time it give his key

Comment: then how should i pass it in argument

Comment: what is result of console.log(event.value); ?

Comment: its giving undefined

Comment: find firebase key and pass it to service

Comment: I am not getting firebase key that's the issue

Comment: if you getting firebase key then after problem will be solve.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing event object you need to pass the event.value to the service

```
 onDelete(event) {
  console.log(event.value);
  if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
    this.service.deleteEnquiry(event.value);
  } else {
    event.confirm.reject();
  }
 }
```

change your service

```
 deleteEnquiry(data){
    console.log(data.$key);
    this.af.list(`/enquirydata/${data.$key}`).remove(data);
  }
```

Comment: can you try to console the event.value in onDelete() method!

Comment: its giving undefined

Comment: for console.log(event) its giving Row {index: 0, data: {…}, _dataSet: DataSet, isSelected: true, isInEditing: false, …}cells: (5) [Cell, Cell, Cell, Cell, Cell]data: {add: "", college: "", degree: "", degreeyop: "", email: "", …}index: 0isInEditing: falseisSelected: true_dataSet: DataSet {columnSettings: {…}, data: Array(2), columns: Array(5), rows: Array(2), willSelect: "", …}__proto__: Object

Comment: where is firebase key ?

Comment: I am not getting it

Comment: if you want to get the $key value from your fire base you need to use this.items = db.list('items').snapshotChanges();

Comment: I have used  return this.af.list('/enquirydata').valueChanges();  in my getData function where should I use this snapshaotChanges()

Comment: you need change the valueChanges to  this.af.list('/enquirydata').snapshotChanges();

Comment: can we use subscribe for snapshotChanges() or we have to use any other method

Comment: you can do subscribe! it wil work same as before and it will give a meta data also using $key you can able to get $key value

Comment: but its not loading the data in table because of metadata

Comment: you need to map db.list('items').snapshotChanges().map(data=>{console.log(data)})

Comment: Have you imported map from rxjs library?

Comment: Have you imported map from rxjs library?

Comment: can you give the whole solution.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1209 in this it is given that map doesn't work on snapshotChanges()

Comment: Inside subscribe you can use map.. did you seee                
  this.users.subscribe( data =>{
   if (data) {
    console.log("Subscribe: ", data);
    data.map( test =>{
     console.log("Map: ", test.payload.doc.data());
    });    
   }
  })

Comment: its giving me data but how to load it into table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165280/discussion-between-faisal-amdani-and-chellappan-v).

Answer (score 0):

Check this doc also :https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md

**snapshotChanges()**
    What is it? - Returns an Observable of data as a synchronized array of 
    AngularFireAction[].

Why would you use it? - When you need a list of data but also want to keep around metadata. Metadata provides you the underyling DatabaseReference and snapshot key. Having the snapshot's key around makes it easier to use data manipulation methods. This method gives you more horsepower with other Angular integrations such as ngrx, forms, and animations due to the type property. The type property on each AngularFireAction is useful for ngrx reducers, form states, and animation states.

When would you not use it? - When you need a more complex data structure than an array or if you need to process changes as they occur. This array is synchronized with the remote and local changes in the Firebase Database